# Help With Parsing Wrapper Class For Xero Contact

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class, parsing

I am trying to update a Xero contact with Payment Terms when a salesforce account is updated. I extracted the json for a contact using Postman and then used json2apex to generate the wrapper class. The issue that I'm having is a null pointer error. "NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object". This is happening at the following line:-

"paymentTerms.Sales.Day = accountTerms.remove('Days').trim();"

The value is certainly not null so I'm thinking that there must be something wrong with the variable. The full wrapper class and failing parser class is below:-

```
public class XeroContactWrapper {

public List<cls_Contacts> Contacts;
public class cls_Contacts {
    Public String SalesforceId;
    public String ContactID;    
    public String AccountNumber; 
    public String ContactStatus;     
    public String Name; 
    public String FirstName;    
    public String LastName; 
    public String EmailAddress; 
    public String BankAccountDetails;
    public Boolean isSupplier;
    public Boolean isCustomer;
    public cls_PaymentTerms PaymentTerms;
    public List<cls_Addresses> Addresses;
    public List<cls_Phones> Phones;
}
public class cls_Addresses {
    public String AddressType;  
    public String City; 
    public String Region;   
    public String PostalCode;   
    public String Country;
    public String AttentionTo;  
}
public class cls_Phones {
    public String PhoneType;    
    public String PhoneNumber;  
    public String PhoneAreaCode;    
    public String PhoneCountryCode; 
}
public class cls_PaymentTerms {
    public cls_Sales Sales;
}
public class cls_Sales {
    public String Day;
    public String Type;
}
```

}

public with sharing class XeroContactParser {
public static Map<Id, XeroContactWrapper.cls_Contacts>   createXeroContactParser(List accountList) {

```
    Map<Id, XeroContactWrapper.cls_Contacts> accountIdToContactWrapper = New Map<Id, XeroContactWrapper.cls_Contacts>();

    System.debug('Account List in Parser = ' + accountList);
    for(Account act : accountList) {
        XeroContactWrapper.cls_Contacts contactWrapObj = New XeroContactWrapper.cls_Contacts();
        contactWrapObj.ContactID = act.Xero_ID__c;
        contactWrapObj.PaymentTerms = createPaymentTermsWrapper(act.Account_Terms__c);
        accountIdToContactWrapper.put(act.Id, contactWrapObj);
    }
    return accountIdToContactWrapper;
}

private static XeroContactWrapper.cls_PaymentTerms createPaymentTermsWrapper(String accountTerms) {

    System.debug('Account Terms = ' + accountTerms + ', Days = ' + accountTerms.remove('Days').trim());
    XeroContactWrapper.cls_PaymentTerms paymentTerms = New XeroContactWrapper.cls_PaymentTerms();
    paymentTerms.Sales.Day = accountTerms.remove('Days').trim();
    paymentTerms.Sales.Type = 'DAYSAFTERBILLDATE';
    System.debug('Payment Terms = ' + paymentTerms);
    return paymentTerms;
}
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. The problem was that the Sales property of the paymentTerms object is null. To resolve the NullPointerException, I instantiated the Sales property before assigning a value to its Day property. I added the following line before the offending line:

paymentTerms.Sales = new XeroContactWrapper.cls_Sales();

And it works!